# How to use regex in Yaml file for Logstash Translate filter?

Tags: regex, yaml, logstash

I am trying to use the Logstash Translate Filter to enrich network data that bro is generating and that I'm ingesting into my ELK stack. For example, here is how I was enriching data manually:

```
translate {
field => "id.orig_h"
destination => "src_comp_name"
dictionary => [
    "192.168.1.1", "Home_Router",
    "192.168.1.150", "My_Laptop",
    "192.168.1.210", "My_Desktop"
    ]
}
```

While this works, it doesn't scale for what I am going to eventually need it for. So I'm trying to move my dictionary to a yaml file and use regex to match IP addresses to assign them tags. So I edited my translate function to:

```
translate {
field => "id.orig_h"
destination => "src_comp_name"
dictionary_path => '/etc/logstash/config/compNames.yaml'
}
```

Below is the contents of roughly what I *want* to do in the yaml file:

```
'^192\.168\.1\.[1-2]$': "Home_Routers"
'^192\.168\.1\.1[0-9]{2}$': "Home_Laptops"
'^192\.168\.1\.2[0-9]{2}$': "Home_Desktops"
```

This would cause `192.168.1.1/2` to be tagged as routers, anything in the `.100-199` range to be tagged as Home_Laptops, and anything from `.200-255` to be tagged as `"Home_Desktops"`. I have tried multiple ways of using regex in the Yaml file, but I'm either getting errors like

> "LogStash::Filters::Translate: can't convert Array into Hash when loading dictionary file at /etc/logstash/config/compNames.yaml"*

Or logstash is correctly starting but not tagging traffic that should be matching.

Any guidance out there on how to implement regex matching in a yaml file for data enrichment via Logstash Translate Filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the translate function:

```
    "exact" => true,
    "regex" => true
```

Comment: Wow, that worked, thank you so much! This was my first experience on the SO boards, thank you for the help in editing the question appropriately as well as the quick and accurate answer!